# Can you help me to split my string

Tags: php, string

How can I split this:

```
{youtube}SOMETHING{youtube}
```

to get `"SOMETHING"` at the end?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: i'm using php for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of {youtube} at the beginning and end are exactly the same, you don't need to split. Simply remove them using `replace()` function. I don't know what language you're using but here is an example in JavaScript:

```html
<script>
var value = "{youtube}SOMETHING{youtube}";  
var result = value.replace(/{youtube}/g, "");
alert(result);  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks bro i'm using PHP

Comment: In PHP, use `$result = str_replace("{youtube}", "", "{youtube}SOMETHING{youtube}");`.

Comment: Hey thank you very much but sorry I made a mistake, the correct code is

{youtube} SOMETHING {/ youtube}

and this code is contained in a variable "$ video" so I do like this:

$ {youtube} video = SOMETHING {/ youtube};

$ string1 = str_replace ("{youtube}", "", $ video);

$ correct_string = str_replace ("{/ youtube}", "", $ string1);

echo $ correct_string;

in the end I get "SOMETHING"

or is there a more appropriate method?

Comment: If the values {youtube} and {/youtube} are fixed and always there at the beginning and end, then using the `substr()` function is better. Try this: `$correct_string = substr($video, 9, 10);`.

Comment: Yes the code is correct, and it works fine but i used this 

$video = $result['video']; $string1 = str_replace("{youtube}", "", $video); $correct_string = str_replace("{/youtube}", "", $string1); echo $correct_string 

to get what i exactly want

Comment: My problem has been solved thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages supports regular expressions. I can strongly recommend to use them.

- JS: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
- C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

In your case the pattern is pretty simple and something like this: `{youtube}(.*){youtube}`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use regular expressions, this would be a simple expression to match `{<sometext>}<interesting>{<sometext>}`.

```
\{\w+\}(\w+)\{\w+\}
```

Then, you can just extract the matched group. Most programming languages support regex, so it should work.